# Show converted file in activity

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a video converter in android studio. I'm able to convert file successfully and can play the resulting file with:

```
File file = new File(filepath);
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent Openintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Openintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
Openintent.setDataAndType(path, "audio/mp3");
try {
    startActivity(Openintent);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

}
```

But I can't find any code to open the resulting folder and show converted file marked. Like we have in windows `Locate file in folder`.

Answer (score 4):

here is how you can open the containing folder for the converted file

```
String folderPath = filepath.substring(0 , filepath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(folderPath);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "resource/folder");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: D/LOCATEERROR: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/ typ=resource/folder }